Orthogonal complement of kernel in a hilbert space
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $f: H \to \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded linear functional. If $W=Ker(f)$ then find $W^\perp$.
This is what I have tried:
$x \in f^*(\mathbb{C})^\perp \iff $ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}, \langle x, f^*(z) \rangle =0\iff$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C},  \langle fx,z \rangle  =0\iff$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C},  z^*fx  =0 \iff fx=0$
Thus x is in the Ker(f).
Thus, $f^*(\mathbb{C})^\perp{^\perp}=Ker(f)^\perp$
Is this okay?
